# Lightning Component - Validate repeating input-form component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, validation, list, aura

I'm working on a Lightning Component for allowing the editing of a list of records. Leaving aside validation, I imagine I would structure it like this:

```
<!--INNER RECORD COMPONENT-->
//attribute type='theobject__c'
//ui:input for every field


<!--OUTER LIST COMPONENT-->
//attribute name='list' type='theobject__c[]'
//aura:repeat value='list'
    //c:innercomponent

//Submit button
```

'Save' at the bottom would, once pressed, perform client-side validation on every record in the list-
 - complete with error messages - before sending off the list to the server for server-side validation.

Assuming that this is an acceptable way to accomplish the task, I'm just wondering what the best way would be to do the following, in terms of both component structure and controller logic:

a) Validate each record on the client-side and show individual error messages. I imagine I'd somehow iterate through the record array and invoke some validation, perhaps passing in the component as a parameter somehow?

b) Error handling on the server side, i.e. if an upsert failure happens, figure out which record(s) it happened on and display that information next to that/those record(s). Would I need to upsert the records one-at-a-time to get sufficiently detailed error information?

Even if you can only answer one of these questions, that would be ace!

Comment: I might be able to help you here. I will reply once I get some time.

Comment: I totally missed out on this question. Were you able to solve this part or do you still need help?